# getting the database info in a Swing table as output

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

I am new to Java and I am practicing some new stuff.. I've started working with the database. therefore I made a to do list application with the MVC pattern.

In my Model I get all the results. In My view I try to output this data as a nice table. The problem is that I don't get any output except for a hardcoded piece of code..

here is the code of my view

```
JTable table = null;

public ToDoListView(ToDoListModel model) {
    this.model = model;

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JTable table = new JTable();

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"To do","Date added"});

    table.setModel(tableModel);

    // this one below is outputted
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"something","1-1-2012"});

    // this should give me all the results.. 
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getRows().size(); i++) {
        tableModel.addRow(model.getRows());
        System.out.println("added");
    }

    add(table);

}
```

in my Model I have this

```
private Vector<String> rijen = new Vector<String>();

    public void getValue() {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
     try {

        con = db.connectToAndQueryDatabase("test", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("connection established");

        st = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT id, item, datum FROM toDoList";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") + "\n" + rs.getString("item") + "\n" + rs.getDate("datum"));
            rijen.add(rs.getInt("id") + "");
            rijen.add(rs.getString("item"));
            rijen.add(rs.getDate("datum") + "");
        }

    public Vector<String> getRows() {
    return rijen;
}
```

This is all the relevant code.. I don't know what I miss or what I do wrong. Could someone show me how I could solve it :)?

Comment: It's good that you reduce the code you show us to the relevant parts of it, but it would be even better if you present us some code that actually compiles. See [http://sscce.org](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also look into using a [`ResultSetTableModel`](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=resultsettablemodel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) of some description.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This JTable attribut ...
JTable table = null;

public ToDoListView (ToDoListModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    setBackground (Color.WHITE);

    // is hidden by this local variable: 
    JTable table = new JTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `ToDoModel` class you add all data in one large `Vector`

```
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") + "\n" + rs.getString("item") + "\n" + rs.getDate("datum"));
        rijen.add(rs.getInt("id") + "");
        rijen.add(rs.getString("item"));
        rijen.add(rs.getDate("datum") + "");
    }
```

Then you loop over that `Vector` to add all those items to the `TableModel`, but that loop is incorrect

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRows().size(); i++) {
    tableModel.addRow(model.getRows());
    System.out.println("added");
}
```

You always add the whole vector instead of just the data for that row.

Combine that with the answer of @user unknown and you might be able to fix your problem

Comment: i've changed it to tableModel.addRow(model.getRows().get(i)); to get every value it contains. but then I get the following error 
The method addRow(Vector) in the type DefaultTableModel is not applicable for the arguments (String) I don't really see any other problem..

Comment: @Reshad I think that error message is pretty clear. You need to pass a `Vector` as parameter, just not always the same one. You want to pass a part of the `model.getRows()` vector (e.g. one containing the first 3 elements for the first row, for the second row one containing elements 4 until 6, ... )